# How to get the next order record in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to get the next order time for the customer who cancelled their orders.

For example, below is the customer order history.

```
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
|   Created date    |   Cancel date     |    OrderID   |  ItemID   |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
| 6-8-2020 10:01:02 | 6-8-2020 10:10:02 |    Order1    |  Item1    |
| 6-8-2020 10:01:02 |    Not cancelled  |    Order1    |  Item2    |
| 6-8-2020 10:01:02 | 7-8-2020 8:10:04  |    Order1    |  Item3    |
| 6-8-2020 12:15:00 |    Not cancelled  |    Order2    |  Item4    |
| 8-8-2020 15:30:30 |    Not cancelled  |    Order3    |  Item5    |
+-------------------+-------------------+--------------+-----------+
```

If the item is cancelled, then the next order time and details after that particular cancellation time needs to be displayed in a new row.

The expected result is

```
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
| Created datetime  | Cancel datetime   | OrderID |  ItemID|Next order datetime|Next order|NextItem|
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
| 6-8-2020 10:01:02 | 6-8-2020 10:10:02 | Order1  |  Item1 | 6-8-2020 12:15:00 |  Order2  |  Item4 |
| 6-8-2020 10:01:02 |    Not cancelled  | Order1  |  Item2 |                   |          |        |
| 6-8-2020 10:01:02 | 7-8-2020 8:10:04  | Order1  |  Item3 | 8-8-2020 15:30:30 |  Order3  |  Item5 |
| 6-8-2020 12:15:00 |    Not cancelled  | Order2  |  Item4 |                   |          |        |
| 8-8-2020 15:30:30 |    Not cancelled  | Order3  |  Item5 |                   |          |        |
+-------------------+-------------------+---------+--------+-------------------+----------+--------+
```

I have tried it using a window function

```
min(Created_datetime) over (partition by userid order by orderID asc rows between 1 following and 1 following) as Nextorder_datetime
```

However, I am getting an incorrect value for order1-item3.

How do I give the condition of ordercancel_datetime > nextorder_date?

Or can I do it using self join? Can someone help me with this?

Comment: is there any primary key in the table?

Comment: Yes, its ItemID

Comment: `ItemID` is not unique, therefore, it is not a primary key

Comment: Actually, in the table ItemID is unique and OrderID is not unique. I have corrected the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, one possibility is to use a self-join

```
select *, 
  t.next_order, 
  (
    select min(orderid)
    from orders o2
    where o2.createdate = t.next_order
  ) next_order_id
from orders o1
cross apply (
  select min(createdate) next_order
  from orders o2
  where o1.canceldate < o2.createdate
) t
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d169037a2b1f454d5bfe8ee8798cd937)